# How do I extract text between two words in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have cell H2 with the following:

```
Person Name: Bill
Date: 10/3/2019
```

How do I extract "Bill" with REGEXEXTRACT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to retrieve `Bill` from `Person Name: Bill\nDate: 10/3/2019` in the cell "H2" using `REGEXEXTRACT`.

#### Sample formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(H2,"Person Name: (.+)")
```

- In this case, I used `Person Name: (.+)` as the regex.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- As other method, I think that you can also use the formula of `=TRIM(INDEX(SPLIT(INDEX(SPLIT(H2,CHAR(10)),1),":"),2))`.

#### Reference:

- [REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was so simple. I was looking at solutions that involved getting the text between other texts and couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: @5146983 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.